# Tailing a file in Clojure?

Tags: file-io, clojure

What would be the best method to tail a file in Clojure? I haven't come across any utilities that would help do so, but ideas on how to build one would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As *kotarak* stated, you could use **RandomAccessFile** to seek to the end of the File. Unfortunately you have to busy-wait/sleep for changes.

Using a lazy sequence you can process the lines "on-the-fly":

```
(import java.io.RandomAccessFile)

(defn raf-seq
  [#^RandomAccessFile raf]
  (if-let [line (.readLine raf)]
    (lazy-seq (cons line (raf-seq raf)))
    (do (Thread/sleep 1000)
        (recur raf))))

(defn tail-seq [input]
  (let [raf (RandomAccessFile. input "r")]
    (.seek raf (.length raf))
    (raf-seq raf)))

; Read the next 10 lines
(take 10 (tail-seq "/var/log/mail.log"))
```

Update:

Something like *tail -f /var/log/mail.log -n 0*, using *doseq*, so the changes are actually consumed.

```
(doseq [line (tail-seq "/var/log/mail.log")] (println line))
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! For some reason, this doesn't seem to act as intended - file changes seem not to be detected!

Comment: (Program stops after first file change)

Comment: Please check my update: Also maybe writing to the file is not "line-buffered"?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `RandomAccessFile` to seek directly to the end of the file and search for linebreaks from there. Not as elegant and short as the `take-last` approach, but also not `O(n)` which might matter for big file sizes.

No solution for `tail -f`, though. Some inspiration might be found in [JLogTailer](http://www.jibble.org/jlogtailer.php).

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
(take-last 10 (line-seq (clojure.contrib.io/reader "file")))
```