# One argument, many functions

Tags: clojure

I have an incoming lazy stream lines from a file I'm reading with [tail-seq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332431/tailing-a-file-in-clojure) (to contrib - now!) and I want to process those lines one after one with several "listener-functions" that takes action depending on re-seq-hits (or other things) in the lines.

I tried the following:

```
(defn info-listener [logstr]
  (if (re-seq #"INFO" logstr) (println "Got an INFO-statement")))

(defn debug-listener [logstr]
  (if (re-seq #"DEBUG" logstr) (println "Got a DEBUG-statement")))

(doseq [line (tail-seq "/var/log/any/java.log")] 
   (do (info-listener logstr)
       (debug-listener logstr)))
```

and it works as expected. However, there is a LOT of code-duplication and other sins in the code, and it's boring to update the code.

One important step seems to be to apply many functions to one argument, ie

```
(listen-line line '(info-listener debug-listener))
```

and use that instead of the boring and error prone do-statement.

I've tried the following seemingly clever approach:

```
(defn listen-line [logstr listener-collection]
  (map #(% logstr) listener-collection))
```

but this only renders

```
(nil) (nil)
```

there is lazyiness or first class functions biting me for sure, but where do I put the apply?

I'm also open to a radically different approach to the problem, but this seems to be a quite sane way to start with. Macros/multi methods seems to be overkill/wrong for now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Making a single function out of a group of functions to be called with the same argument can be done with the core function `juxt`:

`=>(def juxted-fn (juxt identity str (partial / 100)))
=>(juxted-fn 50)
[50 "50" 2]`

Combining `juxt` with `partial` can be very useful:

`(defn listener [re message logstr] 
  (if (re-seq re logstr) (println message)))`


`(def juxted-listener 
  (apply juxt (map (fn [[re message]] (partial listner re message)) 
     [[#"INFO","Got INFO"],
      [#"DEBUG", "Got DEBUG"]]))`


`(doseq [logstr ["INFO statement", "OTHER statement", "DEBUG statement"]] 
  (juxted-listener logstr))`

Comment: This is very elegant and also gave me deeper insights to Clojure (just like the answer above). Thank you, Alex!

Comment: @claj you are very kind. If you wanted to take the level of abstraction further you make a small change and have the second argument to listener itself be a function to be called with logstr. That enables different actions based on input matching. At that point we have basically reinvented a multimethod. Functions as first class entities enable very powerful abstractions!

Answer (score 9):

You need to change

```
(listen-line line '(info-listener debug-listener))
```

to

```
(listen-line line [info-listener debug-listener])
```

In the first version, `listen-line` ends up using the symbols `info-listener` and `debug-listener` themselves as functions because of the quoting. Symbols implement `clojure.lang.IFn` (the interface behind Clojure function invocation) like keywords do, i.e. they look themselves up in a map-like argument (actually a `clojure.lang.ILookup`) and return `nil` if applied to something which is not a map.

Also note that you need to wrap the body of `listen-line` in `dorun` to ensure it actually gets executed (as `map` returns a lazy sequence). Better yet, switch to `doseq`:

```
(defn listen-line [logstr listener-collection]
  (doseq [listener listener-collection]
    (listener logstr)))
```

Comment: Better better yet, switch to `juxt`: `((apply juxt listener-collection) logstr)`

Comment: thank you Michal for helpfully clearing up my mistake with lists! I think that juxt is the most idiomatic solution for me though - thank you amalloy above and Alex below as well for that suggestion!